# Как идентифицировать конкретное письмо при работе с почтой в PHP через IMAP?

Tags: php, email, search, imap

Есть некий почтовый ящик.
На нём есть куча писем (более 1000).
Мне нужно в php-скрипте пройтись по данным письмам и сохранить их себе в базу данных, для того чтобы позднее пользователь мог открыть запись из БД и удалить привязанное к ней письмо на почтовом сервере. Соответственно мне нужно хранить какой-то идентификатор письма у себя в базе и по нему находить его через IMAP на почтовом сервере.

Как это сделать? Возможно ли вообще? В списке php-функций imap_ я не нашел что-либо возвращающее мне уникальный идентификатор письма на сервере и потом позволяющее выбрать письмо соответствующее этому идентификатору.

Answer (score 1):

Функция `imap_uid` возвращает то, что Вам нужно, уникальный id письма. По крайней мере так написано в интернете [Функция imap_uid](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-uid.php)

И есть функция `imap_msgno`, возвращающая текущий внутренний номер для работы с письмом, на основании переданного UID.